# Create two regions with different topological relations in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I would like to create two regions that can have one of topological relation, for example two regions A and B: A covers B, or A contains B, or ... .
How can I create these two regions?
Any help that anybody can offer would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you want this to mean? Maybe give an example? How will these regions affect the behavior of your agents, exactly? Is it stands, the question is too vague to be answered.

Comment: I want to have two agentsets of patches (called region), 
that each of them can has a color. These agentsets can have one of the intersection states, 
for example two agentset can be disjoint and have not any intersection or one of them was inside of other one.
My problem is that I don't know how create two agentsets that have different intersection state each time.

Comment: I've done my best to answer based on the additional clarification. Note that you're free to edit your original question to make it better, rather than just adding comments.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing I have one region:

```
let region1 n-of 20 patches
```

Then here's how I'd make a new region that's entirely contained within region1:

```
let region2 n-of 10 region1
```

Or a new region that's disjoint from region1:

```
let region3 n-of 10 patches with [not member? self region1]
```